# Ruby: How to use the array index method?

Tags: ruby

I would like to read the value "name2" from the key "container" in a YAML file. The key "container" with the value "name2" can be anywhere in the list of containers. In this example it is in the second position. But this is not fixed.

```
[containers.yml]
--- 
containers:
 - container: "name1"
   port: 80
   content: "test"
 - container: "name2"
   port: 8080
```

After reading the YAML file I get the following output with puts.

```
[ruby]
# read the yaml file
my_containers = input('containers')
puts my_containers
# my return: 
# {"container"=>"name1", "port"=>80, "content"=>"test"}
# {"container"=>"name2", "port"=>8080}
```

Could I get the value "name2" with the array method "index" from ruby? Do I have to rewrite the YAML file for this?

```
# get array index by the container name "name2"
num=my_containers.index{|x| [x]['container'] == 'name2'}

# print out the container name "name2"
puts "my second container name is #{my_containers[num]['container']}"
```

Comment: you could simple use `Enumerable#find` like so `my_containers.find {|h| h['container'] == 'name2'} #=> {"container"=>"name2", "port"=>8080}`. If there is no "container" with "name2" this method will return a default value (this defaults to `nil`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `index` with a block:

```
position = my_containers.index { |c_hash| c_hash['container'] == 'name2' }
```

If `position` is nil, you don't have such an element.